# Reference Request: 2-Wasserstein Metric on Wiener Space

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, optimal-transportation, wiener-measure

Suppose that X is the subspace of the set of probability measures on the classical Wiener space $C[0,T]$, for some $T>0$, comprised of Gaussian measures.

In the finite-dimensional setting, the Wasserstein metric between two Gaussian random-variables has a very convenient form.... Are there any known analogues for the infinite dimensional setting?  Especially, in the case of the classical Wiener space?

Comment: This is discussed thoroughly in https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19901470121. See Section 3 and specifically Theorem 3.5

Comment: Perfect, I read through most of the paper last night, it's exactly what I'm looking for.  If you post this exact comment as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed thoroughly in the following reference; see Section 3 and specifically Theorem 3.5.

*Gelbrich, Matthias*, [**On a formula for the $L^2$ Wasserstein metric between measures on Euclidean and Hilbert spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/mana.19901470121), Math. Nachr. 147, 185-203 (1990). [ZBL0711.60003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0711.60003).

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks Nawaf, great answers as always :)